# PWA iOS annoying 20px gap on landscape

Tags: javascript, ios, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing PWA website. Application must be started by clicking on home screen icon. 
The problem is 20px gap that appears after rotating iphone into landscape position. This gap is out of Window object so I cant handle it with js or css. Seems like this is status bar reserved area.
Bug appears only on iOS (except iphone X, XR and similar).

Is it possible to manage the gap? 
Thanks!

Attaching some screenshots 
[image: 2px gap]
Attaching index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest" />   
</head>
<body style="background: red; min-height: 100vh;">
</body>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pwacompat.min.js" integrity="sha384-VcI6S+HIsE80FVM1jgbd6WDFhzKYA0PecD/LcIyMQpT4fMJdijBh0I7Iblaacawc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <-- manifest generator -->

</html>
```

also my manifest file

```
{
  "short_name": "app1",
  "name": "app11",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/i/icon-128.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "/i/icon-256.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "256x256"
    },
    {
      "src": "/i/icon-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "background_color": "#3367D6",
  "display": "fullscreen", // nothing changes with 'standalone' value
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "scope": "/",
  "theme_color": "#3367D6"
}
```

Comment: This isn't the solution but could you force the orientation to portrait or do you need it to work in landscape?

Comment: Application is a game, so it wont start in portrait mode until user rotates device to landscape.

Comment: In the meta tags is the viewport set to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">`? Also have you set the "safe area" using CSS: `padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);`? Just a few things that come to mind

Comment: Great! Had workaround with padding later but seems like not enought.
Post your comment as an answer, hope this helps somebody

Comment: Done! It's posted in the answered area

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Meta Tag**

In the meta tags is the viewport set to:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">`

The key part of this is the `viewport-fit = cover` as the default is auto, by setting it to cover it fills the whole space.

**Safe Area using CSS**

Also have you set the "safe area" using CSS:

`padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);`

The safe area defines the space that is not obscured by the shape of the screen. When you set the viewport to cover it'll fill the whole screen and may cut content off depending on device.