# PWA IOS: Child of body not taking 100% height, gap on bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to make a web app, using angular to make a standalone PWA on IOS, while using the `viewport-fit = cover` meta tag. My CSS looks like this:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
.test{
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

As you can see ideally the entire screen should be red, but no matter what I do it there is always a gap on the bottom. I even tried adding padding to test div, but the gap doesn't go away. Do not this issue only comes up after install the web app using "Add to homescreen" on safari.

Comment: Perhaps you can try this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56724839/1101930

Comment: Yes, I did try that, doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `viewport-fit=cover` tag is kind of a pain to use, but here's what I did to get your code to work:

in the `<head>`:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">    
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

In the `<body>`:

```html
<body>
  <div class="test"> 
  </div>
</body>
```

In the `style.css`:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.test {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

You can see the full code at https://glitch.com/edit/#!/neon-wirehaired-egg?path=index.html and everything running at https://neon-wirehaired-egg.glitch.me/ and Apple has more info on https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/

Comment: Thanks, I had initially some issue but it turns out that I had added position fixed as well to the html tag to "remove" the apple elastic scroll effect that came with the pwa, that also caused me some trouble to get fixed.